# uiRouter routes work from index but not from home

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my Angular project I am using uiRouter. In my app, I have a homepage, a notes index page, and note pages. The urls respectively are:

```
// Home page
$stateProvider.state('home', { url: '^/', ... })

// Notes index page
$stateProvider.state('home.notes', { url: '^/notes/pageno/{pageno:int}', ... })

// Note page
$stateProvider.state('home.notes.note', { url: '^/notes/{id:int}', ... })
```

In the templates for the homepage and the notes index page, I have:

```
<li ng-repeat="note in vm.list">
  <a ui-sref="home.notes.note({ id: note.id })">
    <h2>{{ ::note.title }}</h2>
    {{ ::note.body }}
  </a>
</li>
```

The links to the note pages work from the notes index but not from the home page. On the homepage, they seem to be rendered well, the correct URl is shown in the tooltip when I hover on the link, but when I click nothing happens. No errors are logged. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: The url that you defined look strange to me. Why do you have `{id:int}` ? Are you trying to have a parameter called `id`?

Comment: Yes, as documented [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing). That aspect works.